# Shiny selectInput(multiple = TRUE) problem with mobile devices

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard, shinyapps

I developed a dashboard to monitor covid-19 cases in Brazil using shiny and flexdashboard. It's working fine, but not on mobile devices (at least in some of them). At the sidebar there is a `selectinput()` with `multiple=TRUE`, and the problem is that every time the mobile user tries to select a value to update the plots, the screen keyboard is shown and the whole app is realoaded before the selection (for the correct usage the user needs to select the states and click on "Atualizar" button to update).

I tried to solve it by duplicating the siderbar section, and use `{.no-mobile}` for the first one, and `{.mobile)` for the second, and using `multiple=FALSE` in this second selectinput(). Unfortunately it won't work, and both sections were shown overlapping.

I thought about another way (and i don't know how to do it), using something like `multiple=ifelse("is mobile test",FALSE,TRUE)`.

My questions are: Is there a way to test if the browser is mobile? Is there another approach do solve this problem?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

App link (code embed): https://costafilho.shinyapps.io/monitor_covid19/

Github project: https://github.com/sergiocostafh/monitor_covid19

Problematic line:

`selectInput("estado",h3("Estados"),choices = est_nome, selected = "Sao Paulo", multiple =  TRUE)`

Comment: Have you tried ````selectize = FALSE````?

Comment: `selectize = FALSE` makes multiple selection harder in non mobile devices. It can partially solve the problem for mobile users but is not the desirable option for non mobile. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Selectize is based on selectize.js, which is a hybrid of text and selectInput, therefore the keyboard necessarily has to pop up on mobile for the user to type, otherwise just use the standard selectInput. With regards to the app reloading, I don't have this issue when using a standard shiny app. It's not an issue with shinyapps server as I used it there correctly. It might be an issue with flexdashboard. Consider redesigning app with shinydashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this app on your mobile:

```
library(shiny)

js <- '
function(){
  $(".selectize-input input").attr("readonly", "readonly");
}
'

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("variable", "Variable:",
                   c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                     "Transmission" = "am",
                     "Gears" = "gear"),
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(onInitialize = I(js))
    ),
    tableOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderTable({
      mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  }
)
```

The keyboard should not appear.